# FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 for android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

So first of all I'm trying to do a Client Socket and ASync Task program using android.
It builds and installs successfully, but when I open the application, it crashes and logcat says that
"E/AndroidRuntime(  271): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
E/AndroidRuntime(  271): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()"

```
public class AsyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String... ad) {
        Socket socket = null;
        OutputStream os = null;
        StringBuffer output = null;
        try {
            socket = new Socket(ad[0], Integer.parseInt(ad[1]));
        } catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            os = socket.getOutputStream();
            os.write("GET / \r\n".getBytes());
            os.flush();
            output = new StringBuffer("");
            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(is)));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufReader.readLine()) != null) {
                output.append(line);
                output.append("\n");
            }
            bufReader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return output.toString();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Kindly post your complete LogCat error.

Comment: also highlight the line where error occurs.